# Inner join varchar Issue

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys

I've been reading here some similar issues but my case is not like that.

I have two tables:

- Contacts: name,phone,job,email
- Installers:name,......

Installers.name is foreign key.

I want to show the Contacts table when Contacts.name = Installers.name. But apparently they cannot detect whether they are the same because there is no rows to show.

The Code which I am using is :

```
SELECT Contacts.name,phone,job,email FROM Contacts LEFT JOIN Designers ON Contacts.name = Designers.name;
```

for instance some values are : "Dave Miller" which does not contain any rare character that could be confussing.

I tried also with:

```
SELECT Contacts.name,phone,job,email FROM Contacts LEFT JOIN Designers ON UPPER(TRIM(Contacts.name)) = UPPER(TRIM(Designers.name));
```

But no result at all.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe try using 'LIKE' instead? Check out this website https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: Where is Installers table JOINED?

Comment: what do you mean when you say Where is it JOINED?

Comment: same result @JKirkbride :(

Comment: You should be getting ALL the rows from `Contacts` since you are using a `LEFT JOIN`; unless that table is empty, in which case an empty result is exactly what you should get.